# Winform Save file dialog - localization override

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

My winform application UI is in English. No localization is supported.
When i use the OpenFileDialog dialog, it appears with a language as the hosted OS.
I'd like to keep all dialogs in my app to be in english no matter what the hosting OS language is.

i tried to add this at the init of my app:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Unfortunately it didn't do the job.

Help anyone?

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that there is a bug in Windows that doesn't respect the current thread locale... I don't remember hearing about a workaround. Possibly from this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture as well

CurrentUICulture is responsible for localization

more here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx

and on some blogs
http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/11/1449754.aspx